# Ajax Requests pending after cordova (ionic) app resume

Tags: ajax, cordova, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

I am developing an ionic app and when I resume the app after some time (don't know exactly how much, but doesn't happen if I pause and resume immediately or even several minutes, maybe 30min - 1h), any ajax request I try to make to the api server is in pending and does not actually start (they do not reach the server).

I noticed that the same 'pending requests' behavior happens when there are more then 6 requests already in progress, the 7th will be in pending until one finishes. However, no other requests are in progress when resuming the app.

This happens on both android and ios builds.

Anyone had the same problem?